# How do I put <> around domain in a url?

Tags: support, formatting

I like to use an obviously dummy domain name in a sample url, and put < > around it to emphasize it should be replaced. Unfortunately this is interpreted on StackExchange in a way that hides the whole domain name, displaying http:///rest/of/url. What is the right syntax to escape the < and > characters so they and their contents are displayed?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you can use HTML entities:

- >    &​gt;
- <    &​lt;

Additionally, the brackets are reserved when using preformatted/code markup:

- `<some text here>`

But for examples, the better practice would be to the IANA [reserved domains](http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved), as they will never point to a live website, and search engines will not try to browse them.

- example.com
- example.net
- example.org

[RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) reserves additional top-level domains which may be appropriate:

> ".test" is recommended for use in testing of current or new DNS related code.
>
> ".example" is recommended for use in documentation or as examples.
>
> ".invalid" is intended for use in online construction of domain names that are sure to be invalid and which it is obvious at a glance are invalid.
>
> The ".localhost" TLD has traditionally been statically defined in host DNS implementations as having an A record pointing to the loop back IP address and is reserved for such use.  Any other use would conflict with widely deployed code which assumes this use.

Comment: Note also that you have other options for adding emphasis.  e.g. If you surround part of your text with '**', it will appear in bold.  Surrounding part of your text with backticks puts a grey box around it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write them in between a certain symbol.

`<div>`

If you click edit on this page, you will see it.

Comment: It's called a backtick, and you can simply show it in the screen by putting it in between two spaces, like ` this.